# Getting MID of all the business unit in one go

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, administration

we have over 100 BU and they keep getting created. is there a way to get the MID of all the business unit in some report directly or indirectly for tracking purpose.

Tried out some reports but they give BU details only from which communications are send out

Comment: Please add more details for your problem.

Comment: Have you tried with [SOAP BU AP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/businessunit.htm)I?

Comment: @rahulgawale i wanted to know if there is some way i can  get the MID of all business unit so that don't have to go to each BU in the BU switcher section to see MID

Comment: @LukasLunow i am not sure how to do that